# How to structure a project directory in django?

Tags: django, project, structure

Suppose you are building a Google website. (ok big dream)

Google has web search/youtube/email/news/etc ..

For this site, I'd like to structure my django directory like

```
Google/
       search
       youtube
       email
       news
```

and so on.

How do I structure such a site?
Create an app for each even though I'm not expecting to publish any of the category as an app?

Where would a common stuff (such as user model, utility modules, decorators..) would go, create a **common_app**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications are reusable components for a django project that revolve around a central purpose.  Applications don't need to map directly to your url structure of the website.  While there is a standard structure for a django application to tie in with some of the management commands, such as `tests.py`,  `models.py`, static files at `/static/` you don't need to have any of it to be an application. For example, South is a popular django application used to provide database migrations.  It adds a few management commands to `manage.py`.

When you are adding functionality and it doesn't map directly to the purpose of the application, just create a new one.  So instead of thinking of it a a **common_app**, think about what the purpose of the application would be and how it might be utilized by your other applications.

In my projects, I tend to create a `base` application to handle the base template and static assets that are used in the base template.  I'll create an `accounts` application to handle the user model and implement things like password reset.  To deal with global notifications from any part of my site, I'll create an `alerts` application.  The list can go on for a lot of the common functionality, but it's grouped in a way that revolves around a function and written as if it would be distributed.

So, in your specific case, you'll likely have at least an application for each of the domains such as `search`, `youtube`, `email`, and `news`, but also an application for each common component you might want to use across your core domains.

Comment: search,youtube,email + forum, editor, registration, base, rather than search,youtube,email + common ... makes sense. thanks!